# Start at current date, and continue increment 5 days at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently attempting to increment by 5 days based on the current date.  I am successfully able to do so, with some unwanted results.  While I increment, I am currently pushing them into an array and the list will continue to grow as I increment.  I am trying to only show 5 results at a time. if my current date is dec.16 I only want to show from dec.16-dec.20.  if i increment from there I only want to show from dec.21-dec.25..so on and so forth. As opposed to maintaining the array of dates and slicing, or something along those lines, I would like to reset the array each time I increment. my code is as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.scss";

export default function App() {
  const [days, setDays] = useState(null);
  const [inc, setInc] = useState(5);

  const getDaysArray = async (s, e) => {
    let a = [];
    for (let d = new Date(s); d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
      a.push(new Date(d).toString());
    }

    return a;
  };

  const getDays = useCallback(async () => {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var numberOfDayToAdd = inc;
    let newday = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + numberOfDayToAdd);
    let today = new Date() + inc;
    const data = await getDaysArray(today, newday);
    setDays(data);
  }, [inc]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getDays(inc);
  }, [getDays, inc]);

  const decrement = () => {
    setInc((state) => state - 5);
  };

  const increment = () => {
    setInc((state) => state + 5);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>inc</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>dec</button>
      {days &&
        days.map((item) => {
          return <div>{item}</div>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is a code sandbox for debugging https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-feistel-tj8pj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what are you trying to do but, either you can reset the list or use an array slice like `days.slice(Math.max(days.length - 5, 1))`
For your problem, I edited a solution for you

It was the inc was increased by 5 and then 10 and then 15, so the solution was to delete 4 days from `today` and increment it by inc

```
  const getDays = useCallback(async () => {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    let newday = new Date().setDate(currentDate.getDate() + inc-1);
    let today = new Date().setDate(currentDate.getDate() + inc - 5);
    const data = await getDaysArray(today, newday);
    setDays(data);
  }, [inc]);
```

also don't forget to add `key={item.id}` to your List Component

Comment: Did you test my answer did it work for you? the thing that wasn't clear is it you want to reset the list or keep the list and show only the latest 5 dates.

Comment: ohhh understood, I would like to reset the dates as opposed to keeping the array of dates, the slice seemed to start at the 17th as opposed to the 16th

Comment: ok i edited my answer to reflect this response

Comment: this is perfect @karim, i noticed if it starts on the 16 and ends on the 20, when i increment it will start on the 20th as opposed to the 21st how would you go about tackling that

Comment: with the updated code, when incrementing from 16th-20th the next set of dates starts at the 20th, do i need to add one in order to start on the 21st?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-euclid-1vfjn?file=/src/App.js here is a code sandbox to show you what i mean

Comment: How about now -5 and -1